# How to Fetch all the albums photos from album_id using GraphRequest in Facebook Graph API?

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api

This is JSON format of below code

```
"albums": {
"data": [
  {
    "created_time": "2013-06-08T14:43:51+0000",
    "name": "Profile Pictures",
    "id": "1378810178998660"
  }
```

//Code

```
GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
            loginResult.getAccessToken(),new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {

                    if(response!=null) {
                        final JSONObject jsonObject = response.getJSONObject();

                        try {

                            final JSONObject json_album = jsonObject.getJSONObject("albums");
                            final JSONArray jarray_album = json_album.getJSONArray("data");
                            final JSONObject j_data = jarray_album.getJSONObject(0);
                            final String id = j_data.getString("id");

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
    Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
    parameters.putString("fields","albums");
    //location,picture,education,hometown,interested_in,political,education,locale,age_range,is_verified,photo,relationship_status
    request.setParameters(parameters);
    request.executeAsync();
```

So, I will able to fetch only album-id but not able to fetch the photos related to that album.So, how can I do?

Answer (score 0):

You should fetch `<album-id>/photos`, but I don't know how to solve this with the Framework your are using.

Comment: All this implementation is required in Android.

Comment: Can be done using field expansion syntax, `albums{photos}` ... if you need additional fields of the album object, you have to ask for them the same way, as a comma-separated list inside the {...}

Comment: @CBroe idea will work, too. And because you work with JSONObjects you can implement the paging rather easily.